# Multilingual content and single language admin interface

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I want my site's content to be multi-lingual. I have a language switcher that can toggle between both the English and Spanish translations of a page. I want the administrative interface to always be in English, no matter whether you navigate to it from a Spanish or English translation of the page.

Here is my configuration at */admin/config/regional/language/detection*:

[image]

Here is my configuration at *user/1/edit*:

[image]

My admin interface is always in English, but now my content is also always in English, no matter if I toggle the page to Spanish.

I have tried many settings, including the settings in **Content language detection**.

What is the correct configuration to achieve this?

---

*/es/node/1*

[image]

*/admin/config/regional/language/detection/url*

[image]

*/admin/config/regional/language*

[image]

Comment: What happens if you change the URL path manually on an English page to a Spanish path?  Also, try putting URL first and account admin pages second.

Comment: The content remains in English, but the surrounding interface is in Spanish. Screen shot added to question.

Comment: In your user settings you set site language to english what happens if you logout?

Comment: If I logout, it works correctly I can toggle between the English and Spanish content.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On a fresh install, I could get it working that way:

In `admin/config/regional/language/detection`

- put  *Account administration pages* on top of *Interface text language detection* an enable it of course.
- enable *URL* method as second choice
- enable *Content language detection* and put *URL* on top of detection methods.

[image: Home Administration Configuration Regional and language Languages]

In `user/1/edit` language settings :

- set *Administration pages language* with your preferred language

There are various issues on D.O about that, maybe this is the most relevant  one : [When content language detection is different from interface language detection, the detected language is not applied to the rendered content](https://www.drupal.org/node/2189267).

Apply these patches :

- [When content language detection is different ...](https://www.drupal.org/node/2189267#comment-11049517) (patch #24)
- ['Account administration pages' language negotiation causes 'access denied' in toolbar subtree caching](https://www.drupal.org/node/2868193#comment-12258614) (patch #10)
- [Admin toolbar should always be rendered in the admin language (if set)](https://www.drupal.org/node/2313309#comment-12258602) (patch #40)

Empty caches :

- `$ drush cache-rebuild`

Language dropdown switcher and everything else seems now to be working fine !

An example of spanish content, strings passed through t() are translated, admin toolbar in english...

[image: An example of spanish content]

The same page edited: admin interface fully in english, but content shows  the correct translation....

[image: admin interface fully in english, but content shows the correct translation]

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, the problem with your configuration is: (a) the language switcher disappears (when URL is disabled in Interface text language detection; and (b) only the content is translated at _es/node/1_: anything in code run through `t()` or `|t` remains untranslated. For example: 'Powered by Drupal' does not transform to 'Funciona con Drupal'. I only want _/admin_ pages to be English-only.

Comment: @24ma13wg my bad ! Right, I'v been working a bit more around your problem, and I believe this is working fine now. I'm going to edit the answer. Check in 15mn ;)

Comment: @24ma13wg, for  the sake of clarity and future reference, I rewrote the  answer with exact setup and patches.

Comment: Seems to work. Good answer :-)

Comment: thank you! I cannot understand why this solution is still not out of the box patch less enabled in core... in 2018 August!