# Custom module translations without interface translation

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I'm trying to figure out if I can provide translations to my custom module that are considered part of the "content translation" rather than the "interface translation."

I have a form in my module and some extra text. I've followed all the tutorials and have it working using...

```
interface translation project: contact
interface translation server pattern: 'modules/custom/contact/translations/%language.po'
```

However, the translations are only picked up if I allow for "interface translations." What I want is for my form to be translated, but for it to be considered content.

I don't want all the admin toolbar links and everything drupal admin to change languages too. I want my admin to be able to see the custom module's page in spanish, without setting the drupal admin to spanish too.

Is this possible?

Comment: So you want to translate content entities, but the admin interface should not change the language. See  https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/246793/multilingual-content-and-single-language-admin-interface.

Comment: That did help. I guess this explains why I can't get the toolbar to remain in english though. I see the patch, but the patch has failed testing. I will watch that issue queue.